# Should I use a diamond sword or a trident?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I currently have one trident and one diamond sword in Minecraft Bedrock with both in full durability. Question is, which one is better? I know that the trident can be thrown, which makes it more interesting and have more uses, but the diamond sword has more durability. So, in terms of attack damage, enchantments, durability, diversity, which one should I mainly focus on to use?

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer as it's partially opinion based. Both have the same base attack damage. Personally I would say use the trident when underwater and use whichever one that has better enchantments when out of the water.